# Selenium Can't Find Element Returning None or []

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

im having trouble accessing element, here is my code:

```
driver.get(url)
desc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="somethingcss xxx"]')
```

and im trying to use another method like this

```
desc = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('somethingcss xxx')
```

the element i try to find like this

```
<div data-testid="descContainer">
<div class="abc1123">
    <h2 class="xxx">The Description<span data-tid="prodTitle">The Description</span></h2>
    <p data-id="paragraphxx" class="somethingcss xxx">sometext here
        <br>text
        <br>
        <br>text
        <br> and several text with
        <br> tag below
    </p>
</div>
<!--and another div tag below-->
```

i want to extract tag p inside div class="abc1123", but it doesn't return any result, only return [] when i try to get_attribute or extract it to text.

When i try extract another element using this method with another class, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know why I can't access these elements?

Comment: Is this `xxx` dynamic?

Comment: that's right, i just realized when i'm trying to scroll down little bit and the xxx just appear right after i scroll it down. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have tried the solution I have provided?

Comment: thanks for your solution, but i try to use driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);") too scroll down because it is dynamic and time.sleep(3) to wait for loading page, and my code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css selector to locate p tag.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[data-id^='paragraph'][class^='somethingcss']").text)
```

OR Use `get_attribute("textContent")`

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[data-id^='paragraph'][class^='somethingcss']").get_attribute("textContent"))
```